# How to insert a million records into a mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a two tables.

```
TABLE 1 has id(PRIMARY)|RANK|WEBSITE |ADDRESS
This is filled with a million websites.

TABLE 2 has id(PRIMARY)|tag1|tag2|tag3 ......|tag30
```

I am generating the tags by scraping for the meta tags and other attributes.

I have no problems populating the database for the first few thousand websites. After that, I am not able to populate it. I guess it timed out.

How should I proceed to populate the entire database?

EDIT:

I am getting the data by scraping the urls of the websites dynamically

Comment: Where is the data coming from? From a file or you are generating the data dynamically. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891930/how-do-i-insert-a-large-number-of-rows-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good if you specify error message in your question, output of mysql_error etc (if any).

If your script execution is interrupted because of PHP timeout, you may try to set corresponding configuration parameters (see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) for php.ini configuration for details, and [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) for configuration in runtime).

If reconfiguration is not possible, you may store last record ID you updated in file / database table, and continue execution starting from next ID next time you run your PHP script.

Comment: I am storing the last record ID. This is a better option for me.