# MySQL. Row Count is 0 After Loading Data

Tags: mysql, sql, etl

I loaded ~100M rows into my sql using the 'load data' command. After loading the data, I checked the information schema and saw that the table was populated:

```
SELECT table_name "Table Name", table_rows "Rows Count", round(((data_length +
index_length)/1024/1024),2)  "Table Size (MB)" FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE table_schema = "testDB" AND table_name ="TweetPerson";

+-------------+------------+-----------------+
| Table Name  | Rows Count | Table Size (MB) |
+-------------+------------+-----------------+
| TweetPerson |   88355921 |        19517.00 |
+-------------+------------+-----------------+
```

But when I try to count the rows of the table or use any select statements on it I get row count of 0 or the empty set:

```
select count(*) from TweetPerson; 

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
```

I am using MySQL 5.6. When I loaded the data I used the following commands to speed up the process:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;
SET SESSION tx_isolation='READ-UNCOMMITTED';
SET sql_log_bin = 0;
SET autocommit = 0;
```

What could be the issue here?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
After the load data I tried to set autocommit back to 1 but it did not change anything. I restarted the load from the beginning with autocommit set to 1 and the data loaded correctly.

I can't tell what was the problem with the first data loading but I highly suspect that it had something to do with the autocommit.

Comment: try to execute query using database name in it. `select count(*) from databasename.TweetPerson;`

Comment: @VickyThakor tried. Same results.

Comment: Does `select * from TweetPerson` works?

Comment: No. It returns the empty set

Comment: Have you tried committing the inserts - or turning autocommit back on, which should do the same. _The autocommit mode. If set to 1, all changes to a table take effect immediately. If set to 0, you must use COMMIT to accept a transaction or ROLLBACK to cancel it. If autocommit is 0 and you change it to 1, MySQL performs an automatic COMMIT of any open transaction. Another way to begin a transaction is to use a START TRANSACTION or BEGIN statement. See Section 12.3.1, “START TRANSACTION, COMMIT, and ROLLBACK Syntax”._

Comment: @PaulF. I did turn it back on. I also tried to restart the mysql server. Is it possible to find the load data transaction and commit it manually?

Comment: are you using mysql in cmd or in any tool (i.e workbench)?

Comment: mysql command line. I am using Linux Ubuntu

Comment: `SELECT DATABASE();` execute this and tell me whats the output.

Comment: @VickyThakor. The result is the database I am currently using, where the table TweetPerson is located

Comment: What happens if you try a test and just LOAD DATA on 50 rows?  There have been other threads on Stackoverflow where loading too many entries at one time fails. Good luck.

Comment: @user3741598. When I load my entire data I load it in chunks and it still gives me the above error. I tested it on a smaller file alone like you suggested and it seemed to load well. I want to get to the bottom of my original issue before trying the bulk load again (takes time...). Also, I would like to see maybe I can salvage what I already loaded.

Comment: I recall previous Stackoverflow threads where there were limits to the one-time amount of rows added. Finally found this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/891930/how-do-i-insert-a-large-number-of-rows-in-mysql - looks like a variable max_allowed_packet is the issue. Good luck.